In C, why can a variable holding a char array be assigned to a pointer, but the address of the same pointer cannot?
Consider the following code:
char stringy[] = "There's too much confusion, I can't get no relief!";
char *pStringy;
pStringy = stringy;

This compiles -
stringy is an array of characters, but somehow the pointer pStringy (supposed to hold a memory address) isn't bothered by my storing that string in it.
The following does not compile:
char stringy[] = "There's too much confusion, I can't get no relief!";
char *pStringy;
pStringy = &stringy;

Here, I'm trying to store a memory address (of stringy) in a variable that is supposed to hold a memory address (pStringy), so I'd expect this to work, but C won't have it.
Why?

&stringy produces a char (*)[51], not a char*, which is why the assignment doesn't work. You'd have to change the type of pStringy to make that compile:
char (*pStringy)[51];
pStringy = &stringy;

The first version works because the array decays into a pointer to the first element.

somehow the pointer pStringy (supposed to hold a memory address) isn't bothered by my storing that string in it.

pStringy in the first version holds the address of the first char in the string. It doesn't hold the string itself but just points at it.

In C array types are "special" in that you can't manipulate values of array type at all.  Instead, any time you use an array-typed value in an rvalue context, it is silently converted into a pointer to the array's first element.
Thus, when you say pStringy = stringy;, the array value stringy is converted into a pointer, and since the array element type (char) matches the pointer type, all is fine.
When you say pStringy = &stringy, using the & operator means this is an address context, not an rvalue context, so the array is not converted to a pointer.  Instead you get a pointer to the array, and since pStringy is not a pointer to an array, you get an error.

In most cases C array variable is converted into the pointer toward the first element of the array, and C array subscripting is done by adding that pointer and integer.
On C17 "draft of standard document that are freely available" N2310 Section 6.5.2.1 Paragraph 2,

A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets [] is a subscripted designation of
an element of an array object. The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical
to (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the binary+ operator, if E1 is an
array object (equivalently, a pointer to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
E1[E2] designates the E2 -th element of E1 (counting from zero).

Because of the definition, unsurprisingly, 2[A] is actually well-formed array subscripting expression.
So the variable stringy has type char[], which is compatible to char *.
On the other hand, &stringy has type (char[]) *, which is compatible to char **, not char *.

Thank you BoP. Maybe I was too settled to handle array as a pointer. Is my understanding for array subscripting still correct?

Would you mind writing the name of the various variable types you mentioned? char[], char*, (char[])*, char**, char*? Of these, I'm only familiar with char* and char[].
Also talking bout "compatibility" for data types is a first... I've only ever understood this in terms of "same" or "not same" data type

char[] is char array. char * is pointer of char(or char pointer). (char[]) * is pointer of (char array). char ** is pointer of pointer of char, or char double pointer for short. double is also a type name, so be careful of misunderstanding when you mention "double pointer".

For explanation of multipointers, please check this.
